# Language flags position - bad viewing on mobile phone

Tags: wordpress, position, flags

i have problem with language flags on my testing wordpress web: `http://www.multisite.jecool.net/`

I paste this code to header.php:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<a href="http://www.multisite.jecool.net"><img style="position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 1700px; z-index: 10; width: 26px; height: 15px; border: none;" title="Čeština" src="http://www.multisite.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/cz_flag.gif" alt="Čeština" /></a>
<a href="http://www.multisite.jecool.net"><img style="position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 1730px; z-index: 10; width: 26px; height: 15px; border: none;" title="English" src="http://www.multisite.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/en_flag.gif" alt="English" /></a>
<a href="http://www.multisite.jecool.net"><img style="position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 1760px; z-index: 10; width: 26px; height: 15px; border: none;" title="Deutsch" src="http://www.multisite.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/de_flag.gif" alt="Deutsch" /></a>
</div>
```

Flags are ok, but position is strange. When i open it on desktop pc on 2 diferrent monitors = flags are not on same place = its depending somehow on monitor size. On 24" monitor or on 29" monitor. I want place this flags on one place and it must to be viewed equally well on different monitors. And on mobilephone this flags make bigger web with white background.

Can someone take me tip or help? I just want 3 flags viewing and placing at same spot, thats all. I thought it would be trivial, but no :-). Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your flags (note the changes in css)

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; z-index: 10;">
 <a href="http://www.multisite.jecool.net"><img style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" title="Čeština" src="http://www.multisite.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/cz_flag.gif" alt="Čeština" /></a>
 <a href="http://www.multisite.jecool.net"><img style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" title="English" src="http://www.multisite.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/en_flag.gif" alt="English" /></a>
 <a href="http://www.multisite.jecool.net"><img style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" title="Deutsch" src="http://www.multisite.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/de_flag.gif" alt="Deutsch" /></a>
</div>
```

Into header section:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
//flags here...
```

Comment: Hari thank you so much! I try solve this problem many times and you fix it. Thank you again!